# Can I checkout a new branch in remote repo after commiting the changes?

Tags: git, github, open-source

I have cloned a repo and made some changes and then after commiting it I tried to push it using `git push` but it shows error like permission denied to **myusername** and unable to access. and i can't seem to resolve this error with any of other projects also. and i forgot to create a new branch earlier so I'm thinking that could be the case for this error or not? So how do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you the owner or administrator of the repo you are pushing to?

Answer (score 0):

Did you clone it from a repo you owned?  (If not you likely don't have permission to push).  But assuming the source repo is yours (so you cloned it from url that looks something like github.com/your-username/your-repo-name):

To answer your 1st Q:  Sure go ahead and checkout a new branch and commit your changes there if you'd like.  From where you are right now assuming you've committed (or not) your changes you can run:

> git checkout -b new-feature-branch

Assuming you have permission you'll be able to push this new branch to the remote with:

> git push -u origin new-feature-branch

But your 2nd question hints at some sort of permissions issue...  If it's not just that you don't own/have permission to access the remote you'll need to share the error/elaborate more on what the setup is and what's going wrong

Comment: I don't own that repo, I've just forked it and cloned and made changes. then I tried to commit those and push it to my remote repo but it repeatedly shows an error like ```remote: Permission to (source repo) denied to (myusername)``` ```The requested URL returned error: 403``` . and now i created a new branch and tried to push it there using ```git push -u origin new-branch``` but it still shows the same error

Comment: Check what git thinks is your remote - is it showing your fork or the original?
> git remote -v

If it's showing the original you need to add a remote that you have permission to push to.
> git remote add origin {REMOTE_URL}

Comment: As a side point, you might find the docs on git by Atlassian useful, I think they're some of the best and easiest to understand git docs  https://www.atlassian.com/git